# Javascript Radio Button Won't Print Value

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have a radio button selection, and I want to print the selected value. Here is my code for that:

```js
function submit() {
  let Q1 = document.querySelector('input[name="question1Selection"]:checked').value;
  console.log(Q1)
}
```

```html
<div id="QUESTION1" class="questionContainer">
  <h1 class="questionNumTitle">Question 1</h1>
  <h3 class="questionQuery">How old are you?</h3>

  <div class="questionSelection">
    <div class="selectionContainer">
      <input type="radio" id="ageQ1" name="question1Selection">
      <label for="ageQ1">0-18 years old</label><br>
    </div>
    <div class="selectionContainer">
      <input type="radio" id="ageQ2" name="question1Selection">
      <label for="ageQ2">19-40 years old</label><br>
    </div>
    <div class="selectionContainer">
      <input type="radio" id="ageQ3" name="question1Selection">
      <label for="ageQ3">41-64 years old</label><br>
    </div>
    <div class="selectionContainer">
      <input type="radio" id="ageQ4" name="question1Selection">
      <label for="ageQ4">65+ years old</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><br><br>

<input type="submit" onclick="submit()" value="Submit"/>
```

However, when you select a value and press "submit," the console mysteriously just prints "on." What is going on here? Why won't it print the value?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your value for input:radio  is stored in label

Comment: None of the `<input>`s have a `value` attribute. `"on"` is the default value. Read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#additional_attributes).

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [bad practice](/q/11737873/4642212). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way to listen for events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value is stored inside the label not radio button.

The `input` has not value which is default `on`

You could try to get index of the checked item and return the label value.

Use `+` to get sibling `label` of input button

```js
function submit(){ document.querySelectorAll('input[name="question1Selection"]').forEach((i,index)=>{
if(i.checked) console.log(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="question1Selection"] + label')[index].textContent)
});
}
```

```html
<div id="QUESTION1" class="questionContainer">
  <h1 class="questionNumTitle">Question 1</h1>
  <h3 class="questionQuery">How old are you?</h3>

  <div class="questionSelection">
    <div class="selectionContainer">
      <input type="radio" id="ageQ1" name="question1Selection">
      <label for="ageQ1">0-18 years old</label><br>
    </div>
    <div class="selectionContainer">
      <input type="radio" id="ageQ2" name="question1Selection">
      <label for="ageQ2">19-40 years old</label><br>
    </div>
    <div class="selectionContainer">
      <input type="radio" id="ageQ3" name="question1Selection">
      <label for="ageQ3">41-64 years old</label><br>
    </div>
    <div class="selectionContainer">
      <input type="radio" id="ageQ4" name="question1Selection">
      <label for="ageQ4">65+ years old</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><br><br>

<input type="submit" onclick="submit()" value="Submit"/>
```

Comment: If you just want the text content of the label, a much easier solution would be to remove all `for` attributes from `<label>`s and all `id` attributes from `<input>`s and nest each `<input>` inside their respective `<label>`. Then it’s just `theSubmitButton.addEventListener("click", () => console.log(document.querySelector("#QUESTION1 input[name='question1Selection']:checked")?.closest("label").textContent.trim() ?? "No selection."))`.